GFCI in box with two hots?
Remodeling my kitchen and electrician said i needed to update an outlet to GFCI.  They did install it.
There are two branches off the GFCI.  LoadRight and LoadLeft, each with their own wiring and 1 outlet each.
LoadRight works fine.
LoadLeft immediately trips when i use it.
Opened the box and see tje line cables have 2 hots (red and black) and 1 neutral (white).
The black line goes to the GFCI and the white goes to the GFCI.
LoadRight pulls from the GFCI.
LoadLeft ( the one that keeps tripping) pulls neutral from the GFCI, but is twist tied to the red line, which is not on the GFCI.
I'm assumimg it trips beacuse omly one line goes through the GFCI?
I moved the black LoadLeft wire to the GFCI and it works fine now.
But what do i do with that live red line?  Right now i just capped it.  Should i go back to the panel and pull it from the breaker so it is dead?  Is it dangerous to leave a capped live line in the outlet box?

I would suggest just having the electrician return and fix it on their dime, since they're the one that did the initial installation.

Do you happen to have a photo of the circuit breaker(s) that control both of the loads?

As crip659 pointed out, this is almost certainly an MWBC. The electrician may have had good reasons not to put in a double-GFCI breaker:

They are expensive. They vary depending on brand/type and source (big box vs. supply house) but many are $100 - $150. That compares to around $20 each, sometimes less, for a GFCI/receptacle, so 2 GFCI/receptacle is around $40.
They may not even be an option for certain older panels or (yes, they are still out there) fuse boxes.
Many homeowners associate "GFCI" with "GFCI/receptacle" - the electrician may have gotten tired of installing GFCI/breakers only to have homeowners ask them to change to GFCI/receptacle "just like in the bathrooms".
Ease of reset. I probably have to reset a GFCI in my house on average once a year or so (i.e., only once for the entire house, not once per circuit, and that's including all the kitchen countertop receptacles, bathroom receptacles and some others that have been gradually added in other locations - come to think of it, the one I recently had was not long before I had to replace the UPS plugged into it, so that failing UPS may actually have been the cause, but that's not important now) but for people who are concerned about frequent resets, using GFCI/receptacle is preferred.

But the cost is the big one in most cases. However, this one was installed incorrectly. The electrician should have known better, of course, but more importantly, they should have tested everything before leaving, so that's really bad.
In any case, the best solution is:

From the panel cable, pigtail the white neutral to go to GFCI line neutral and to Load/Left Neutral.
Black wire to GFCI line hot (no change)
Red wire to Load/Left hot
Load right cable black hot and white neutral to load hot and neutral of GFCI
Replace the first "load left" receptacle with a GFCI/receptacle

By doing this you safely use the MWBC (key is to pigtail the neutral so that if one of the neutrals is disconnected the rest of the circuit still works properly), provide GFCI protection for both left & right receptacles (which putting them both on the one GFCI load will also do) and give you the MWBC benefit of double power so toaster on left and George Foreman grill or whatever on the right can run at the same time without tripping a breaker.

Kitchen MWBCs really do not give “extra power”: the code mandates at least two 20A / 120V circuits serving kitchen countertop receptacles. The power will be there regardless. The MWBC is just a tiny bit less expensive to install (one /3 cable to pull instead of two, and the wire is cheaper to buy since it’s 4 conductors instead of 6).

@nobody Extra compared to capping the red wire. But yes it might be part of the required circuits

It sounds like it was a multi-wire branch circuit before.  A MWBC allows more power(have the kettle and toaster on together) with only one neutral on one circuit, if done right.
The electrician should have used a GFCI double breaker in the panel, instead of a GFCI receptacle.
Good is capping off the red wire in the box.  Better is also removing it from the breaker, if you are comfortable with doing it.
I do prefer to turn off the main breaker before putting my fingers in there.  Oops do not hurt as much if no power.

Disabling the red branch would almost certainly be a code violation: the NEC requires a minimum of (2) 20A countertop circuits in kitchens.

@nobody we really don't know what other circuits may have been added at other times


LoadRight pulls from the GFCI 's "LOAD" terminals.

There, I added the bold for you.

LoadLeft ( the one that keeps tripping) pulls neutral from the GFCI 's "LOAD" terminal, but is twist tied to the red line, which is not on the GFCI.

There's your problem right there. You can't take one wire from LOAD and the other wire from LINE. You must take both hot+neutral, or neither.
Since it's impossible to take the red hot from LOAD, you must take the neutral wire from LINE.
Electrician should've known that LOL.
Feel free to use the LINE terminal as a splice device. The back-wiring method is fine here, it's not bad like "backstabs".
Also since Load Left won't have any GFCI protection, it'll need a separate GFCI receptacle.  LoadRight needs labeling "GFCI Protected" per instructions 8(C).
How I know the instruction line is 8(C) is because UL approves all instructions and provides example instructions, most manufacturers adopt that rather than risk failing.
